# menu item activation in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, menu, internationalization, drupal-7

I want to do something like this in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree('main-menu');
    [ get current page/path ]
    [ IF we are on page1 THEN set menu item "item1" active ]
    print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
    ?>
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`menu_set_active_item()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_item/7):

```
if ($_GET['q'] == 'page1') {
  menu_set_active_item('item1');
}
```

Doing the in page.tpl.php will probably be too late in the process for this to actually work. The docs page recommends doing it early on in the page build, for example in `hook_init()`.